# Something with the turbo

Tags: vw, turbocharger, jetta, turbo-lag

My Vw Jetta 2005 tdi 1.9L has trouble accelerating in low gears. For instance as soon as I switch gear the car accelerates slow and when the rpm reaches around 2-3 it has that power, sometimes. In the 5th gear it goes to 70mph and takes even longer to go faster. Does my car need a new turbo?

Comment: Is this new behavior or something which has been consistent? The VW TDI isn't known to have gobs of power. Diagnosing whether it's a turbo issue is going to take some more information than you've provided. Is there any noise from the turbo? Is there any oil consumption out of the ordinary? Is there volumes of black smoke out the back end during acceleration? (Also, check the rear of the vehicle at the tail pipe and look for carbon/oil deposits there.)

Comment: It is consistent. Although sometime it feels like it has more power than other times. The turbocharger wastegate actuator was recently changed and the car turbo worked perfectly fine. Until recently this problem started happening. There is no leakage, no noise, no smoke from the car. It just doesn’t want to accelerate like before.

Comment: Are you sure the new wastegate actuator was hooked up (activating) correctly?

Comment: I hope so. It was working for like 3 to 4 months before this problem occurred.

Comment: Have you checked for leaks, split hoses, split intercooler etc. Does it sound any different/more wheezy?

Comment: Have you read for OBD codes?

Comment: Yeah and got a P0299